# fortran openmp nested loop communication overhead

Tags: fortran, openmp

My goal is to move away from MATLAB and toward doing most of my work in Fortran. One of these efforts has been substituting parallelization via MATLAB's parfor loop with Fortran openMP directives. This is always quicker, but for some reason CPU utilization (as measured by taskmgr) is lower using openMP than parfor (particularly for smaller problems). My hypothesis is that this is due to communication overhead and that if CPU utilization was closer to 100% (like MATLAB), then the code would be much faster for the small problems. My question is two-fold:

1. Is there a way to improve the efficiency (with openMP directives) of the following code?
2. If not, what is the source of the inefficiency and what would you suggest to remedy it?

Attempted (unsuccessful) resolutions:

1. adding clause collapse(5) (for the 5 nested loops)
2. declaring everything explicitly (i.e., not use default(shared))
3. KMP_SET_BLOCKTIME(1000) to keep threads open until next omp parallel do execution

CPU utilization data (Windows 7 64-bit, dual quad-core intel xeon 3Ghz):

- Small problem (*_pts = 5): 
  Fortran (openMP), time: 40s,  CPU util.: 60% 
  MATLAB (parfor),  time: 45s,  CPU util.: 90% 
  -> MATLAB takes 1.125 times as long
- Medium problem (*_pts = 6):  
  Fortran (openMP), time: 78s,  CPU util.: 75% 
  MATLAB (parfor),  time: 96s,  CPU util.: 90% 
  -> MATLAB takes 1.231 times as long
- Large problem (*_pts = 7):  
  Fortran (openMP), time: 150s, CPU util.: 100% 
  MATLAB (parfor),  time: 205s, CPU util.: 100% 
  -> MATLAB takes 1.367 times as long

Example:

```
    do while (converged == -1)
    istart = omp_get_wtime()               ! Iteration timer start
    !$omp parallel do default(shared) private(start,state,argzero)
    do i5 = 1,Oepsr_pts
     do i4 = 1,Ozeta_pts
      do i3 = 1,Oz_pts
       do i2 = 1,Or_pts
        do i1 = 1,Opd_pts
         start(1,1) = pfn(i1,i2,i3,i4,i5)
         start(2,1) = pfx1(i1,i2,i3,i4,i5)
         start(3,1) = pfx2(i1,i2,i3,i4,i5)
         state = [Gpd_grid(i1),Gr_grid(i2),Gz_grid(i3),Gzeta_grid(i4),Gepsr_grid(i5)];
         ! Find optimal policy functions on each node
         argzero = 0.d0
         call csolve(start,nstate,npf,nshock,Opd_pts,Or_pts,Oz_pts,Ozeta_pts,Oepsr_pts,Omono_pts,state, &
                        Smu,Schi,Sr,Sy,Pomega,Ptheta,Psigma,Peta,Pzbar, &
                        Prhor,Ppi,Pphipi,Pphiy,Prhoz,Pzetabar,Prhozeta,Pbeta, &
                        Gpd_grid,Gr_grid,Gz_grid,Gzeta_grid,Gepsr_grid,Gmono_nodes,Gmono_weight, &
                        pfn,pfx1,pfx2,argzero)
         ! Store updated policy functions
         pfn_up(i1,i2,i3,i4,i5) = argzero(1,1)
         pfx1_up(i1,i2,i3,i4,i5) = argzero(2,1)
         pfx2_up(i1,i2,i3,i4,i5) = argzero(3,1)
        end do
       end do
      end do
     end do
    end do
    !$omp end parallel do

    ! Policy function distances    
    dist_n = abs(pfn_up - pfn);  
    dist_x1 = abs(pfx1_up - pfx1);
    dist_x2 = abs(pfx2_up - pfx2);

    ! Maximum distance
    dist_max(it) = max(maxval(dist_n),maxval(dist_x1),maxval(dist_x2));

    ! Update policy functions
    pfn = pfn_up;
    pfx1 = pfx1_up;
    pfx2 = pfx2_up;

    ! Check convergence criterion
    if ((it > 11) .AND. all(dist_max(it-10:it) < Ptol)) then 
        converged = 1;
    else if (dist_max(it) > 10 .OR. it > 2500) then
        converged = 0;
    end if

    ! Iteration Information
    iend = omp_get_wtime()
    if (mod(it,3) == 1 .OR. converged == 1 .OR. converged == 0) then
        call itinfo(tstart,istart,iend,it,dist_max(it));
    else
        it = it + 1
    end if
end do
```

Comment: It seems that the Fortran implementation is better than the Matlab version at all problem sizes and gets better as the problem becomes larger.  I'd be more concerned if either of those weren't true.  Why spend a lot of effort on something that runs in 40 s, unless you have to run that very many times?

Comment: One issue in the code is that `it` appears to only be incremented when it is not congruent to 1 mod 3; are you sure you want the increment in the `else` clause?  Also, can this code fully use one CPU when run without OpenMP?

Comment: Without collapsing the loops, your code cannot get more parallelism than `Oepsr_pts`; is that enough to explain the limited CPU utilization?  I think also that `i1`...`i4` should be marked as `private` so they can iterate separately for each iteration of the `i5` loop.

Comment: 1) I plan to run it very many times (40,000) for different parameterizations of the problem, that's why I'd like to run the small problem.
2) it is incremented in the call to itinfo (not shown)
3) I will try collapse one more time to verify, but it did not work when I've tried it in the past. I have also specified i1...i4 as private to no avail.

Comment: OK, it looks like collapse did fix it after all. I'm not sure exactly why I didn't think it worked; I may have been using a different computer at the time with a different number of cores.

Comment: Simply do what @JeremiahWillcock stated: make `i1` to `i4` private. Collapsing the loops does it as a side effect.

Comment: If you want to run 40000 independant instances of your code, I suggest to forget parallelization of a single instance, and run many instances in parallel. This will be much more efficient.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but the 40,000 parameterizations are not independent; they are drawn sequentially.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the collapse clause eliminated the inefficiency.
    !$omp do collapse(5)
Otherwise, as Jermiah Willcock pointed out, only the outer loop would run in parallel. I believe I was testing it on a computer with 6-cores and the outer loop happened to have 6 points, so there was no loss in efficiency at the time. It was only when I switched to a computer with more cores that this became a problem. Good to know!

Thank you M.S.B. and Jeremiah for your quick and helpful responses. All is better now!